# Expand main div to fit with content - CSS troubleshoot

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the div expand to fit the content contained in a `<section>` tag for my HTML and CSS page.  The thing is that it cuts off midway through the content and I can't get this to work.

So far I've experimented with setting `overflow:auto` but to not much success - the inner container scrolls but I'm looking to make the whole page scroll.

Can someone have a look and help me out?  JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xgT5/

Comment: Which div do you want to expand?

Comment: The `<section>` element within the `<div id='mainContent></div>`.  The `<section>` element will expand depending on the content - consisting of `<p>`,`<img>` and `<table>` elements.

Comment: Please compact your example down to the most necessary components. No one wants to trawl through a lot of unnecessary stuff to try to find a specific problem. Help us to help you :)

Comment: It's as if the `<footer>` element is always displayed at the bottom of the monitor.  I want the user to be able to scroll down the page and see that at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of `height:100%`  on `#mainContent` and replace it with `float:left`. That should do the trick. Let me know if that resolved the issue.

For the footer, git rid of position absolute and replace it with float:left, width:100%:

```
footer {
float: left;
background-color: #CAD0C8;
border: #000 1px;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are fixing #footer and it makes to float outside a content layout. So you need just add to the `section` `padding-bottom :45px /*footer height*/`

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `#mainContent`.